# MassTransit exception encountered: System.Threading.Channels.ChannelClosedException: The channel has been closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, activemq-classic, masstransit

We have an ASP.NET Core application targeting .NET 3.1.
We are using MassTransit to send and consume messages and ActiveMQ as message broker.

We are using these MassTransit packages

```
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit" Version="7.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.ActiveMQ" Version="7.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.AspNetCore" Version="7.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.2.2" />
```

We have many consumers, declared like this:

```
services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
{
    busConfigurator.AddConsumer<CreateLeadConsumer>();
    busConfigurator.AddConsumer<CreateOrderConsumer>();
    busConfigurator.AddConsumer<InvoiceCreatedConsumer>();
    busConfigurator.AddConsumer<PhoenixContractCreatedConsumer>();
    busConfigurator.AddConsumer<PhoenixDocumentCreatedConsumer>();

    ConfigureBus(busConfigurator, activeMqOptions);
});
```

We defined these ActiveMqOptions

```
var activeMqOptions = Configuration.GetSection(SodexoActiveMQOptions.SectionName).Get<SodexoActiveMQOptions>();
EndpointConvention.Map<InvoiceCreatedMessage>(new Uri(QueueFormatter.FormatToAllowConcurrency(activeMqOptions.LocalQueues.InvoiceCreatedQueue)));
EndpointConvention.Map<CompanyOrderDto>(new Uri(QueueFormatter.FormatToAllowConcurrency(activeMqOptions.GlobalQueues.CreateOrUpdateClientQueue)));
EndpointConvention.Map<BeneficiaryWithProductDto>(new Uri(QueueFormatter.FormatToTopic(activeMqOptions.GlobalQueues.CreateOrUpdateBeneficiaryQueue)));
EndpointConvention.Map<CreatePhoenixOrderMessage>(new Uri(QueueFormatter.FormatToAllowConcurrency(activeMqOptions.GlobalQueues.CreateOrderQueue)));
EndpointConvention.Map<PhoenixOrderCreationMessage>(new Uri(QueueFormatter.FormatToAllowConcurrency(activeMqOptions.GlobalQueues.PhoenixCreateOrderQueue)));
EndpointConvention.Map<CancelOrderMessage>(new Uri(QueueFormatter.FormatToAllowConcurrency(activeMqOptions.GlobalQueues.CancelOrderQueue)));
EndpointConvention.Map<CancelOrderMessage>(new Uri(QueueFormatter.FormatToAllowConcurrency(activeMqOptions.GlobalQueues.CancelOrderQueue)));
EndpointConvention.Map<DocumentCreatedMessage>(new Uri(QueueFormatter.FormatToAllowConcurrency(activeMqOptions.LocalQueues.DocumentCreatedQueue)));
```

Our consumer work fine most of the time, the payload are well consumed.

But sometimes an exception is thrown :

```
[MassTransit.ReceiveTransport] R-FAULT "activemq://localhost:61616/{name of the queue}" System.Threading.Channels.ChannelClosedException: The channel has been closed.
  at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.Run[T](Func`1 method, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
  at MassTransit.ActiveMqTransport.Transport.ActiveMqSendTransport.SendPipe`1.Send(SessionContext sessionContext) 
  at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
  at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
  at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
  at GreenPipes.Internals.Extensions.TaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<OrCanceled>g__WaitAsync|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
  at MassTransit.Util.PendingTaskCollection.Completed(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
  at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next) 
  at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
```

Since we get this exception, the message goes to the error queue.

To avoid this exception I added a retry behavior on our application. When an exception is encountered the message is resent in the queue. It is working fine with other exception but not with this one.

As soon as the `System.Threading.Channels.ChannelClosedException` is thrown the message is retried and is consumed. But just after the message is consumed the message still goes into the error queue.

Here is a much more clear view of the logs, as you will see there is a pattern:

```
As you will see, the first time, the application try to publish the message to a queue, but a ChannelClosedException is thrown. 

The second time, the message is correctly published, because we can see final logs, and also because I checked with the targeted consumers.

 

[22:39:13.647 INF] [] [ECommerce.Messaging.Consumers.CreateOrderConsumer] Receiving order message

 --> First time we get the message

[22:39:13.924 INF] [] [ECommerce.Messaging.Consumers.CreateOrderConsumer] Sending phoenix reorder creation message for enterprise number 754887949

 

[22:39:13.927 WRN] [] [MassTransit.ReceiveTransport] R-RETRY "activemq://localhost:61616/create-order" "8ee80000-56b0-0050-5f50-08da74c70f82" MassTransit.Context.RetryConsumeContext<MassTransitMessaging.CreateOrderMessage>

System.Threading.Channels.ChannelClosedException: The channel has been closed.

   at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.Run[T](Func`1 method, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at MassTransit.ActiveMqTransport.Transport.ActiveMqSendTransport.SendPipe`1.Send(SessionContext sessionContext)

   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at MassTransit.EndpointConventionExtensions.Send[T](ISendEndpointProvider provider, T message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at ECommerce.Messaging.Consumers.MessageNotifier.NotifyAsync[T](T message, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/ECommerce.Messaging/Consumers/MessageNotifier.cs:line 18

   at ECommerce.Messaging.Consumers.CreateOrderConsumer.Consume(ConsumeContext`1 context) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/ECommerce.Messaging/Consumers/CreateOrderConsumer.cs:line 96

   at MassTransit.Scoping.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)

   at MassTransit.Scoping.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)

   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)

   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)

   at GreenPipes.Filters.RetryFilter`1.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)

 

[22:39:14.031 INF] [] [ECommerce.Messaging.Consumers.CreateOrderConsumer] Receiving order message

 --> Second time we get the message

[22:39:14.255 INF] [] [ECommerce.Messaging.Consumers.CreateOrderConsumer] Sending phoenix reorder creation message Phoenix reorder creation message is sent for enterprise number 754887949

 

 

[22:39:14.281 INF] [] [ECommerce.Messaging.Consumers.CreateOrderConsumer] Phoenix reorder creation message is sent for enterprise number 754887949 

[22:39:14.281 INF] [] [ECommerce.Messaging.Consumers.CreateOrderConsumer] Reorder was created for company 754887949 

--> Success, it means that the message has been correctly sent
 

[22:39:14.291 ERR] [] [MassTransit.ReceiveTransport] R-FAULT "activemq://localhost:61616/create-order" ID:CEBESVC-BA5AP08-54759-637950758237778584-1:0:1:1:1 "00:00:00.6544301"

System.Threading.Channels.ChannelClosedException: The channel has been closed.

   at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.Run[T](Func`1 method, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at MassTransit.ActiveMqTransport.Transport.ActiveMqSendTransport.SendPipe`1.Send(SessionContext sessionContext)

   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at GreenPipes.Internals.Extensions.TaskExtensions.<>c_DisplayClass4_0.<<OrCanceled>g_WaitAsync|0>d.MoveNext()

— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —

   at MassTransit.Util.PendingTaskCollection.Completed(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)

   at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)

--> The message has been sent BUT we get this error !
```

It is annoying because we have to check for each message in error queues if this is real error or not.

Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce this behavior with my local environment.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this problem? we are experiencing the same.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're encountering was fixed in MassTransit version 8.1.0, where the ActiveMQ library was updated to the official version. Updating to this or a newer version should help resolve this issue.

Comment: Maybe it's also because I don't use await context.ConsumeCompleted; or return Task.CompletedTask;